# Windows Program To Programmatically Capture Phone Call Data?

Tags: modem, phone-call

I would like to use a program that can capture phone-call data from the modem on a pc and run a batch file so I can request a url from a browser with the params set to the phone number.

I did this a while back with a very nice and cheap($30) piece of software for windows but cannot find or remember what it was called for the life of me.

Does anyone know of such a program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it

http://www.callclerk.com/

You can run a batch file when someone calls you and use the call data as parameters.

I open firefox and request a url with params, which is hosted on my lan.